# Kali - Live Session has no Install Kali application

Tags: linux, usb, installation, multi-boot, kali-linux

Good day all

When attempting to install Kali to my HDD, Kali ofcourse being on my USB drive: I ran into 2 problems.

Source of ISO : [Kali Official Site v2016.1](http://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2016.1/kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso)

//reason for point 2

**1.** From Kali boot menu, selecting graphical install, follows with/and proceeds to installation where I get the CD-ROM error.

**Problem:**

**2.** Alternatively, I booted into the live session (top menu option), booted to desktop where I searched for "Install Kali". From videos and forums this is the application that should install Kali, unfortunately there was no "Install kali" application.

*does this mean Kali is actually installed on my usb drive, thus implying no need for the "Install kali" application?*

I used YUMI, my USB drive contains Ubuntu 16.04, Kali, Windows 10. YUMI allows os install from a single usb drive.

Comment: Why don't you try making a dedicated live USB to install Kali linux.

Comment: Also kali rolling does not have a 'install kali' option, like kali 1.0 or kali sana